# Check whether quarters are in sequential order using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having quarter list.

```
var quarters = new Array();
quarters.push("Q1 2014");
quarters.push("Q2 2014");
quarters.push("Q4 2014");
quarters.push("Q1 2015");
```

Here quarters are not in sequence. "Q3 2014" is missing.
How to check whether these are in sequence or not using jquery?

Comment: Given the format of the string this will not be straightforward. Can you amend the array to contain objects, something like `{ q: 1, y: 2014 }`?

Comment: Iterate and compare with the previous ?

Comment: Why is this tagged as C#? Seems like plain JS to me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Sort the array (you'll need a callback comparison function to pass to `sort`)
2. Loop through the array comparing the "current" entry against the previous, looking to see if it's exactly one quarter later

In both cases, you'll probably need something that parses the strings so you have a quarter number and a year, rather than a string combining them. The parsing is trivial enough that you can use regex for it:

```
var parts = str.match(/^Q(\d) (\d{4})$/);
```

...and then `parts[1]` is the quarter and `parts[2]` is the year.

I'm not usually a fan of providing all the code, but as there's now incorrect code kicking around the question:

```
var quarters = [
    "Q1 2014",
    "Q2 2014",
    "Q4 2014",
    "Q1 2015"
];
var prev, i, curr;

// Sort the quarters according to their quarter value (see `qval` below)
quarters.sort(function(a, b) {
    return qval(a) - qval(b);
});

// Find gaps by starting at the beginning and comparing each entry
// to the one just in front of it
prev = qval(quarters[0]);
for (i = 1; i < quarters.length; ++i) {
    curr = qval(quarters[i]);
    if (curr !== prev + 1) {
        console.log("Gap found between " + quarters[i - 1] + " and " + quarters[i]);
    }
    prev = curr;
}

// `qval` parses a quarter string ("Q2 2014", for instance) and returns a
// a number for the quarter: The year times four plus the quarter
// within the year (e.g., 8058 for Q2 2014). For easy comparison.    
function qval(quarterString) {
    var qv, parts;

    parts = quarterString.match(/^Q(\d) (\d{4})$/);
    if (!parts) {
        throw "Invalid quarter string: '" + quarterString + "'";
    }
    qv = (parseInt(parts[2]) * 4) + parseInt(parts[1]);
    return qv;
}
```

[Live Copy](http://jsfiddle.net/DZr8R/)

Comment: @James : What if list is in not in sequence.                                         var quarters = new Array();
    quarters.push("Q1 2014");
    quarters.push("Q2 2014");
    quarters.push("Q1 2015");
    quarters.push("Q3 2014");

Comment: @user1120418: I refer you to #1 above: *"Sort the array"* Sorting arrays in JavaScript is trivially easy: `theArray.sort(function(a, b) { /* ...code that compares a and b, returning a negative number if a is "less than" b, a positive number if a is "greater than" b, or 0 if a is equal to b */ });`

Comment: @user1120418 as suggested by T.J. you would simply sort the array before you perform the comparison. Given the nature of the text the default string sort should work ok, however, you can supply a custom sorter if you need more control. See [update](http://jsfiddle.net/NhZqG/2/).

Comment: @James: The nature of the text *doesn't* lend itself to a simple string sort, you'd get `Q1 2014` followed by `Q1 2015` before `Q2 2014`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder D'oh, yeah I was thinking because `2014` would be less than `2015` but obviously a string comparison will do it on a progressive character basis. In that case it would need to be a custom sort then.